# Sticky footer is at bottom of screen, instead of bottom of pafe

Tags: html, css

So every time I make a website, I have issues with the footer. Now, after some googling, I found the following:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

I tried to apply it, but it didn't really work out... Instead of the footer staying in the bottom of the page, it just sticks at the bottom of my screen.

This is where the footer sticks:

[image: Footer]

That is, when I fully scroll to the top of the page, the bottom of google chrome's display on my mac.

This is the HTML I use:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- A lot of content -->
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: url(../img/bg.png);
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    padding: 0,0,60px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #292929;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
```

So how is it that this footer confuses the bottom of my screen with the bottom of my page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you change the footer's `position` to `relative` then it will appear at the bottom of the wrapper div.

http://jsfiddle.net/vh23mfpk/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your `body` and `html` has a height of `100%`
When you assign a 100% height to the body and html elements, they won't expand beyond the height of your window regardless of their content.

You should remove those properties and instead add `min-height: 100%` to `html`

You should inspect the sample page you just linked to see the properties of `html` and `body`.